# Execute SonarQube analysis locally using Gradle without pushing

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

In my **build.gradle**, I have a `sonarqube` task from `'org.sonarqube'` plugin. Whenever I run `gradle sonarqube`, I got the below error:

```
You're only authorized to execute a local (preview) SonarQube analysis without pushing the results to the SonarQube server. Please contact your SonarQube administrator.
```

I don't have admin access to SonarQube server in my organisation, please let me know how to run SonarQube analysys locally (preview analysis) without pushing result to server

(I know there is a **SonarLint** plugin to IntelliJ to analyse code withn IDE, but the process to have it installed involves a lengthy approval-seeking process :) So I'll have to do without it)

**Update** Adding my sonarqube task config

```
sonarqube {
    def shortBranchName = versionDetails().branchName

    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", 'http://dummy.net/'
        property "sonar.forceAnalysis", "true"
        property 'sonar.projectName', "[" + shortBranchName + "] " + rootProject.name
        property 'sonar.projectKey', "${sonarQubeProjectBaseKey}"
        property 'sonar.branch', shortBranchName
        property 'sonar.projectDescription', "[" + shortBranchName + "] " + rootProject.name
        property 'sonar.sourceEncoding', 'UTF-8'
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured the gradle defaults as mentioned in https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforGradle-1-Activatethescannerinyourbuild ?

Comment: @segfault I did, please see updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable preview mode and local HTML reports by passing these extra properties:

```
-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
```

However, this feature has been deprecated some time ago, and may not work at all with recent versions of SonarQube and the Gradle scanner.

The old documentation is here, in any case:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Getting+Issues+Report+in+Preview+Mode

Comment: Seems like this no longer works.   Maybe this answer is no longer relevant?

Comment: `The preview mode, along with the 'sonar.analysis.mode' parameter, is no more supported. You should stop using this parameter.` so it looks like this answer no longer works